# Gradle increment version while publishing

Tags: gradle, nexus

For an artifact currently published I like the Gradle to publish on Nexus with version incremented.

Consecutive publishes should have:

```
com.myorg-myartifact-1.0.0
com.myorg-myartifact-1.0.1
com.myorg-myartifact-1.0.2
```

I need the version alone to be incremented +1 on consecutive publishing. The artifact is not a jar/war file but a zip containing db dump, so I don't want to use the snapshot repository.

Comment: You can pass the version from command line and add it to artifact. It's also a good idea to provide `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Good idea. Is there a way I can get existing version in Nexus? so that I can just append 1 to it?

Comment: Not sure. What artifact are we talking about?

Comment: You could use the Nexus REST Api to get the latest version and increment from there but you should already have the latest version right there in your source code the creates the artifact so why not just increment there?